# Dependent columns in MFC list control

Tags: mfc

In CListCtrl, is there any way to have a value of one column dependent on another?
For example- My grid has four column, I want column #4 to always have value equal to column#2 - x( x is some variable)

Is there any direct way to this in MFC.

I want column#4 to update data automatically whenever data in column#2 changes.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you have to do this yourself. But it's really not a big deal.

Comment: What event does MFC send when data in some column in inserted/pasted/modified?

Comment: When inserting items through [CListCtrl::InsertItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx#clistctrl__insertitem), pass `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` as the *lpszItem* argument for the dependent item. Whenever the system needs to display the dependent item, it will call back to your code to construct it.

Comment: Can you give me example on how to use LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK .Do I have to pass some callback method?

Comment: I tried using LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK but this is only useful when items are inserted. In the case of editing existing items framework will not request for display information.